# Customer Attribute Value not Option_ID

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-attribute

i have add a customer attribute `Salesman` (select type, admin will asign salesman to customer at backend from list), any customer will have asigned a salesman who is responsible for contact with this customer.

Problem is, when i'm trying to access this attribute, i only get `option_id` number.

```
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php
-----
 $this->addColumn('salesman', array(
            'header'    => 'Salesman',
            'index'     => 'salesman'
        ));
```

returns number not a text value.

accessing this way:

```
$customerObj  = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_attribute ')->load($customer_id);
$attr = $customerObj->getAttributes('salesman');
```

returns the same number "option_id".

Is there any way to access value of this specific attribute?
I would not preffer to change all `select` attributes to return value :)

Can anyone help me with it?  All previous replies for similar questions, wasn't helpful.

Comment: have you created customer attribute Salesman with source model?

Comment: can you share you source model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$attributeCode = 'salesman';

$customerObj  = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);

$textvalue = $customerObj->getResource()
            ->getAttribute($attributeCode)
                ->getSource()
                    ->getOptionText($this->getData($attributeCode));
```

OR

```
$customerObj  = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);

$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'salesman');

$text = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionText($customerObj->getSalesman());
```

Comment: 2nd solution works :)   Thak you very very much